# Проблема 301 редиректа со старого адреса на новый

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ряд ссылок на старом адресе, и при обращении к ним должен срабатывать 301 редирект. В htaccess вставил данный код, все успешно редиректит:

```
Redirect 301 /first/second https://domain.ru/first/second
```

При обращении к olddomain.ru/first/second происходит редирект на domain.ru/first/second

Но также есть другая ссылка, на которую почему-то правило редиректа действует некорректно. Пример:

```
Redirect 301 /first/second/link https://domain.ru/first/second/link12
```

Откроется domain.ru/first/second/link

Что я упускаю? Спасибо.

UPD: Кэш чистил, через инкогнито пытался

Comment: Вангую закешированный неправильный редирект. Почистите кэш браузера. Проверьте в режиме инкогнито.

Comment: Чистил, пытался через инкогнито, не выходит

Comment: О, ещё строчки местами поменять

Comment: Менял, результат не изменился. Но благодарю за внимание к моей проблеме